# Customiz Apache solr autocompelete module

Tags: apache

I want to display apache solr autocomplete keywords suggestion to be group like:-

----Suggestion from texonomy-----

- term1
- term2
- term3

----Suggestion from products---

- product3
- product4
- product10

----Suggestion from pages---

- contentX
- contentY
- contentZ

Actually I am new in drupal, so somebody can help me how's it possible.